# Bounding $\chi(g)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

For a character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$,

$$|\chi(g)|\leq \dim(\chi)$$

Obviously the inequality is strict for $g=1$, and if $\dim(\chi)=1$ also for $g\neq 1$.

Is there a better bound for $\chi(g)$ if we assume 1) $g\neq 1$, and 2) $\dim(\chi)>1$?

Comment: Presumably you mean for $\chi$ to be the _character_ of a representation, not the representation itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, taking $\chi$ to be a sum of $n$ copies of the trivial character for some $n>1$, then $\chi(g)=n$ for all $g$.

It also does not help if you assume additionally that $\chi$ is irreducible.  For instance, let $G=D_8$ and let $\chi$ be the character of its usual two-dimensional representation as symmetries of a square.  Then $\chi$ is an irreducible character of positive dimension.  However, if $g\in G$ is the element corresponding to a rotation by $180^\circ$, then $g\neq 1$ and $\chi(g)=-2$.

(In fact, more generally, if $g\in Z(G)$ and $\chi$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$, then $|\chi(g)|$ is always equal to $\dim \chi$.  This is because the representation must send $g$ to a scalar multiple of the identity, by Schur's lemma.)

Comment: Your example is  for *real irreducible* character. I am curious to know about complex irred characters.

Comment: My example is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$.  If it were reducible, it would be a sum of 1-dimensional representations and thus the image of the representation would be abelian.

Comment: Yes. I got confused with cyclic groups 2-dim real irred representation. Thanks for being kind to my impatient remark.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that the set $\{g\in G\mid |\chi(g)| = \chi(1)\}$ is called the center of the character, and the center of the group is the intersections of the centers of the characters.